# How does gravity affect "Timeless" particles like photons?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, photons, time-dilation

Just finished a class a while ago and in it was discussed the nature of gravity being due to mass' effect on time etc. etc.

My question is: how then does gravity effect something like a photon, which has no "real" time, or pointlike particles?

Is the curvature in spacetime and the whole "travelling in geodesics" shtick correct, or is it the gradient in time? Maybe both? Am I an idiot or can someone relate to my woes.

tl;dr pls help

Thanks!

P.S
As the robot commands I'll specify my question:

My question in effect is whether the gravity of photons and pointlike particles is caused by the curvature of space or of time or both, and if so, then how does time apply to those "timeless particles"

Comment: Can you clarify why you're calling the core of general relativity "shtick"? What precisely bothers you about it? Don't forget the mass-energy equivalence, which means that photons can be affected by gravity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is a "timeless particle"?

Comment: @WillO By timeless I mean massless, given that their 4 velocity is oriented purely through space they don't travel through time at all. Hence "timeless"

Comment: The 4 velocity of a massless particle is lightlike.  By your criterion, such particles don't travel through space either.  Do you also want to call them "spaceless"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "'travelling in geodesics' shtick" is indeed correct.

Although a null worldline (the kind of worldline that represents a pulse of light) does not have proper time, it does have an affine parameter. A massive worldline's affine parameter is the proper time, so for a massive parameter you can think of things like the curvature at a specific proper time. For a null worldline you can still reasonably discuss the curvature at a specific affine parameter, you just cannot call the affine parameter "proper time".

For the geodesics to work it is only necessary to have an affine parameter. It is not necessary that the affine parameter must be proper time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!